# How to Use Virtual Tree View in a Dynamically Updating Tree?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

I am using Delphi XE3 and Virtual TreeView.

I want to use Virtual TreeView to implement a tree, when clicking "Start" button, the program will search all files and folders under a drive recursively, then add them one by one to the tree, just like Windows Explorer.

After reading the "The virtual paradigm" in the help document carefully, I know that I cannot use AddChild or InsertNode, as they are only for compatibility purposes. One should use OnInitNode and OnInitChildren to initialize the nodes.

But it is really difficult to use the virtual paradigm to my case. Currently I can figure out one algorithm:

1. Define an internal data structure, called TMyInternalNode, to store the data of one tree internal node, as well as the relationship between internal nodes, such as parent, child, sibling, etc.
2. In OnInitNode and OnInitChildren events. Try to find the location of the node, via its level and relationshp between other nodes. Then find the corresponding internal node for the node(that may be a little difficult, sometimes one may traverses the whole internal node tree to find the correct one. After finding the correct one, initialize the node with the internal node data.

This algorithm seems to be complex and time-consuming. Is there better way to implement such a case?

Answer (score 3):

The virtual paradigm is interesting and useful and all. But the reality is that you don't *actually* want to use the virtual paradigm.

The purpose of the **virtual** model is not actually fetch any data until the user asks for it.

If you start by getting a list of folders in the root of the C: drive:

- Intel
- MSOCache
- PerfLogs
- Program Files
- Progream Files (x86)
- ProgramData
- Users
- Windows

The point is that **you stop there**. The goal in the **virtual** paradigm is to only populate the tree **as needed**.

If the user then chooses to expand a node, **that** is when you fetch children:

- Intel
- MSOCache
- PerfLogs
- Program Files
- Progream Files (x86)
- ProgramData
- Users

  - **Alan**
  - **David**
  - **Ian**
- Windows

And then you can either:

- rely directly on node.Index to figure out what each node represents
- or store a piece of arbitrary data with each `PVirtualNode` to help you link it to the underlying data

But you're not really doing that:

> when clicking "Start" button, the **program will search all files and folders under a drive recursively**, then add them one by one to the tree, just like Windows Explorer.

You're loading **everything**, and want to show all the millions of files.

Now there's absolutely nothing wrong with that. The Virtual Tree can create a million nodes nearly instantly. It is awesome. I will regularly load 100,000 rows of customers, invoices, sales orders, etc. And the users can then `Ctrl+F`, or export the rows to Excel.

But in your case it's just not *"virtual"*; because you are allocating memory for 500k files *up-front*.

The virtue of the virtual paradigm is to save memory.

- You just **say** there are 500k nodes,
- and the tree will **pretend** there are 500k nodes,
- but it doesn't actually allocate 500k nodes worth of memory

### It's ok to be not virtual

In your case, it's ok to *not* be virtual. If you fundamentally want everything to load up, regardless of what the user has expanded, scrolled, or can see, then it's fine. And then you *can* use:

- AddChild

But you also realize that allocating 450,409 `TMyFileInfo` objects up front goes against the idea of saving memory until needed.

### Virtual version

You could *make* it virtual, by only fetching children for folders the users has opened. But that has downsides. Many times i **want** the program to fetch everything in the background for me.

Comment: Sorry that I may misrepresent my opinion. What I need to show initially are just a list of folders in the root of the C: drive:. When user clicks one of them, then the folder will expand with all the childrens, just like Windows Explorer.

Comment: I do not need to load everything at the beginning.